# How do I perform this search in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the structure of my database in Ruby on Rails:

- user have many notes
- notes have many categories
- categories have many notes

The relationship between notes and categories is `has_many :through`, I have a model named `NoteCategory` and a `note_categories` table.

The note model has a date field, which represents the date the note was created.

I get the notes for the user with this line:

```
current_user.notes
```

How can I provide a date and get back the categories for all the user's notes that were created on that date? Thanks for reading.

edit: Forgot to mention that I also need the categories to be ordered by the created_at field of the note they are attached to.

edit 2: here are the actual associations

user.rb

```
has_many :notes
```

note.rb

```
belongs_to :user 
has_many :note_categories
has_many :categories, :through => :note_categories
```

category.rb

```
has_many :note_categories
has_many :notes, :through => :note_categories
```

Answer (score 2):

Given you have

```
class User
  has_many :notes
  has_many :categories, :through => :notes
end

class Note
  has_many :categories # <-- source reflection
end
```

then use this finder:

```
user.categories.all(:order => 'notes.created_at')
```

or

```
user.categories.find :all, :order => 'notes.created_at'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it out. A quick question, the field I want to sort on is actually notes.created_at, i.e. the categories are sorted based on the created at date of the note they are attached to. Is that what your code does?

Comment: I got the following error:
Invalid source reflection macro :has_many :through for has_many :categories, :through => :notes.  Use :source to specify the source reflection.

Comment: Usually it complains about source reflection if it cannot find the source of the association in the model referenced by :through. I guess you use a "has_and_belongs_to_many" approach - not sure if it would accept that.

Comment: Hey, sorry I took so long to respond! I have added the model definitions into the original question. Thanks for your help!